# Can't compile C program as PostgreSQL stored procedure

Tags: c, postgresql

everyone. I try to make simple example of how to create stored procedures in PostgreSQL written in C language. When compiling "test.c" there's an error "Unknown type Datum". I use Version 1 Calling convention. PostgreSQL 9.1 is installed on my server under Ubuntu 11.10. Please help. By the way does anybody have step-by-step example of creating stored procedures in C language? Thanks

Comment: post relevant code, which will save the guess-work for everyone.

Comment: Based on the "Unknown type" diagnostic, it sounds like you've forgotten to `#include` a header file from the PostgreSQL implementation.  Unfortunately, I don't know what that file would be.

Comment: You should really show the whole compiler error sequence. Copy and paste.

Comment: The problem was I use #include "postgres.h" instead of #include "/usr/include/postgresql/postgres.h". Now I can't compile shared object. `code` cc -shared -o /usr/include/postgresql/foo.so /usr/include/postgresql/foo.o. 
cc: error: /usr/include/postgresql/foo.o: No such file or directory
cc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote up a mind dump while I was doing this awhile back on FreeBSD.  Here is the link in case it might help.

[Compile C function to stored procedure brain dump](http://flycereal.blogspot.com/)

Comment: Thank you, very much! I'll try as soon as get my pc

Answer (score 1):

1. Search for the postgres server includes path 
   (Debian Wheezy = /usr/include/postgresql/9.1/server/)
2. Change `#include` directives inside the `PostgreSQL` example (foo.c) from `#include ""` to `#include<>`
3. To compile, add the include search path with the directive

   -I (gcc -fpic -c foo.c -I/usr/include/postgresql/9.1/server/)
4. Continue as its said in the Postgres documentation

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/xfunc-c.html